# Unable to add CRM 2011's Organization service as Service Reference to VS project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, service-reference

I have problem accessing `Organization Service` when I try to add it as a `Service Reference` in Visual Studio. However, I can Access the Service in browser. I have tried to add `OrganizationData` service and there is no issue with that.

```
An Error occurred while attempting to find service at 'http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxx/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc'.
```

[image]

**Error Details**

```
There was an error downloading 'http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxx/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxx/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxx/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would reference the SDK assemblies (`Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll, Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll, Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll`) vs adding a service reference. They give you very clean proxy objects for the `OrganizationService` and greatly simplify authentication with the `CrmConnection` class. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602970%28v=crm.5%29.aspx) is a sample.

You can find them on the [MSFT Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004) and on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies/) just make sure you use the version that matches your version of CRM including UR.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am aware about this option as well. But my only concern is that why I am getting this error. By adding the service, I can use Intelisence rather than writing the names of fields.

Comment: You won't get intellisense on fields by adding a service reference. MSCRM doesn't expose entity types in the wsdl. You can still use the SDK references and [CrmSvcUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx) to generate early bound types.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention CrmSvcUtil. that is what I use most of the time with Service Ref. Anyway because of the time I am have done the coding using SDK references. But to get to the root of the error I got, I still want to keep this question open.